# "Потому что" в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

**"Это потому что ты гулял по набережной"**.

Нужно ли ставить запятую между "потому" и "что". Ведь это простое(?) предложение. Каким членом предложения выступает здесь слово "это"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1.**  **Это потому что ты гулял по набережной.** Здесь ЭТО ― указательное слово, отнесенное к  местоименной части союза. По структуре ― придаточная часть сложного предложения при отсутствующей главной, использован прием парцелляции (членения предложения).
Пример: Это потому что он тоже хорошо владеет айкидо.

**Вариант 2.**  **Это потому,  что ты гулял по набережной.** Здесь ЭТО  ― местоименное существительное в роли подлежащего в главной части сложноподчиненного предложения.

Пример:   Это потому, что отец Михаил меня заметил. [Александр Солженицын. Матренин двор (1960)].

**Чаще встречается вариант с запятой**: союз расчленен, логически выделено придаточное причины.